# What does $(-1)^{2/3}$ equal?

Tags: arithmetic, arithmetic-functions

I figured that according to the exponent laws it should equal $1$ since: $$(-1)^{2/3} = ((-1)^2)^{1/3} = 1^{1/3} = 1$$
 But according to wolframalpha and google it equals something imaginary. Why is this?

Comment: Why would you write such a thing in the first place? And what would **you** intend it to mean if you did so?

Comment: It depends on whether you are looking for a real number or all possible complex numbers (mixed real and imaginary parts). But $1$ is a correct solution here. It's just not the only possible solution if you are going to allow imaginary parts.

Comment: $a^{bc}=(a^b)^c$ does not necessarily work for negative numbers and fractions.  $-1=-1^1=(-1^{\frac{2}{2}})=(-1^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}=1^{\frac{1}{2}}=1$ showing that $-1=1$.  Of course, we know this isn't true so there must be some equality in the chain that shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: If your solution would be right, just raise both sides to the $3/2$ power. Then $[(-1)^{2/3}]^{3/2}=(-1)^1=-1$. On the right hand side $1^{3/2}=1$, so $-1=1$. This is the same problem noted by @JMoravitz

Comment: Chose the ''Use the real‐valued root instead'' option in WA and you find your solution. So the question is: what is the difference between '' real‐valued  root'' and ''principal root''?

Answer (score 3):

This is so because you can not use rules of exponents for negative bases.

A similar argument as of yours will lead to following $$i=(-1)^{1/2}=(-1)^{2/4}=1^{1/4}=1$$

Answer (score 2):

In general, fractional powers are multivalued functions.  For  complex numbers $a$ and $r$, $a^r$ is defined as $\exp(r \log(a))$, where $\log(a)$ is any branch of the natural logarithm of $a$.  In this case, $\log(-1) = i \pi + 2 n i \pi$ for arbitrary integer $n$, so 
$$(-1)^{2/3} = \exp((2 i \pi + 4 n i \pi)/3)$$
has three possible values: $\exp(0) = 1$, $\exp(2 i\pi/3) = \frac{-1+i \sqrt{3}}{2}$, $\exp(4 i \pi/3) = \frac{-1 - i \sqrt{3}}{2}$.
I suspect Wolfram Alpha is using the principal branch $n=0$.

Comment: Okay so it has multiple values and one of them is 1. Does this mean that 1 equals several other complex numbers since 1 = 1^(1/3) = exp(i2nπ/3), which is a complex number?

Comment: No, it means there are three **different** values.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever seen the equality $e^{\pi i} = -1$? We can actually use this to solve this puzzle!

Let's try  $(-1)^{\frac{2}{3}} = (e^{\pi i})^{\frac{2}{3}} = e^{\frac{2}{3}\pi i}$. If you cube that, you do get $1 = e^{2 \pi i}$.

For more info, you can learn about roots of unity , complex roots, and the Euler Identity.

Answer (score 0):

If we are only looking for real solutions, we can allow $(-1)^{\frac ab}$ for $\frac ab$ written in reduced form and $b$ odd.

$$(-1)^{\frac ab}=\begin{cases}1 &\text{ for } a\text{ even } \\
-1 &\text{ for } a\text{ odd } \end{cases}$$

This way, we will never have a fraction with even on top and bottom, which causes problems. If we allow $b$ to be even, then we can end up taking an even root of a negative number which isn't allowed in the "real world".

Robert Israel gives the full answer and the reason why Wolfram Alpha gives the answer that it does.